# lodash _.sortedIndex returns last index element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I'm using lodash `_.sortedIndex` to determine the position the element should go.

If the array being checked is small enough it works perfectly. However that array can grow quite large and after it has increased size `_.sortedIndex` returns the last element of the array instead of the actual position

```
var checkObject = {name: John, lastname: doe}
var arrayOfObjects = [1...25]; //The objects would be similar layout to checkObject
var position = _.sortedIndex(arrayOfObjects, checkObject, 'name')
```

This works fine, and the position returned would be the appropriate spot.

However in the instance below:

```
var checkObject = {name: John, lastname: doe}
var arrayOfObjects = [1...75]; //The objects would be similar layout to checkObject
var position = _.sortedIndex(arrayOfObjects, checkObject, 'name')
```

It seems to either return its correct position or just return 76

Is there a way to ensure that the returned position is correct?

This is call called from a function inside angular using the following:

```
$scope.$evalAsync(
    function (data) {
        someFunctionToCheckIndex(data)
    }
);
```

Comment: Are you sure that the array is sorted properly (by name) before calling `sortedIndex()`?

Comment: The list is sorted by name (served from the server). The issue most likely is the result of non standard characters in the array (server uses a c++ library to sort properly)

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a script?